# No se puede usar un valor de tipo "void *" para inicializar una entidad de tipo "int **"

Tags: c++, vscode, matrices

estoy haciendo (o intentando) hacer una calculadora de matrices, pero tengo un problema con `void *malloc(size_t _Size)` y es que me muestra un error que no puedo usar `malloc` para inicializar `int**`. Si alguien puede ayudarme lo agradecería muchísimo, es para un proyecto escolar.

aquí dejo la parte del código:

```
int**  reg(int f, int c){
int i, j, d;
int** matriz = malloc(f*sizeof(int));
for(j = 0; j < f; j++)
matriz[j] = malloc(2*c*sizeof(int));
for(i = 0; i < f; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < c; j++)
    {
        printf("Ingrese el valor en %d - %d: ", i+1, j+1);
        scanf("%d", &matriz[i][j]);
    }
}
for(i = 0; i < f; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < c; j++)
    {
        matriz[i][j+c] = abs(matriz[i][j]);
        if (matriz[i][j+c] != 0)
        {
            for (d = 0; matriz[i][j+c] > 0; d++)
            {
                matriz[i][j+c] /= 10;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            d = 1;
        }
        if (matriz[i][j] < 0)
        d++;
        matriz[i][j+c] = d;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`void*` es un tipo de dato que se limita a contener una dirección de memoria.

Lo único que necesita `malloc` es la cantidad de bytes a reservar y devuelve la dirección de memoria que acaba de reservar. No sabe para qué la vas a usar. Por ello el tipo es `void*`.

Con `void*` no puedes leer la información de la memoria. Entonces el resto de punteros, permiten que el programa sepa como interpretar la información en ella.

La conversión de cualquier puntero a `void*` es implícita. Pero de `void*` a cualquier otro es explícita.

Simplemente tienes que convertirlo precediendo la variable o el valor de paréntesis y el tipo a convertir. Así:

```
int* entero = (*int)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

---

Según indicaste en las etiquetas de la pregunta estás usando C++. Si es así, es muy recomendable que uses [`new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) y [`delete`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete).

Con `new` no necesitas indicar los bytes ni realizar conversiones e inicializa la memoria, llamando al constructor por defecto en el caso de usar una clase.

Esto es equivalente al ejemplo anterior:

```
int* entero = new int;
// Liberas la memoria
delete entero;
```

O si quisieras reservar memoria para más de un elemento, existen las variantes `new[]` y `delete[]`.

```
int* arreglo = new int[10];
// Liberas la memoria
delete[] arreglo;
```

Hay una regla simple para saber cuál `delete` usar: Si usaste `new`, debes liberar la memoria con `delete`. Si usaste `new[]`, liberas con `delete[]`.

Comment: entiendo, muchas gracias. Ya ejecuté el programa y lo corre bien. Pero me quedo con una duda, la variante `delete[]` donde podría colocarlo y como?

Comment: Ya la edite. Ahora si quedó claro?